# Can't connect to askubuntu with Ubuntu SSO

Tags: bug, launchpad

I could not log on my [original account](https://askubuntu.com/users/85273/cm-t) throught SSO on askubuntu.

I've tryed on Firefox, Chromium (fresh install with the purpose of this test, no extension).

How to reproduce:

1. New private window: askubuntu.com
2. Click on Log in
3. Choose `Log in with Launchpad`
4. You are redirected to Ubuntu SSO log in form
5. Log in, it ask you if you are OK to log on launchpad
6. Click Yes, you are redirected to launchpad, with many question about how you want to give access to your lp account
7. Select an option *(no access, Read Non-Private data, Change Non-Private data, Read Anything,  Change Anything)*
8. You are redirected on askubuntu with an error message:
9. `Launchpad Login Failed. Please try logging in again.`
10. you can try again with any other options at step 7. *(I've tryed them all, all failed)*

Looks like an oidc error, or a config somewhere between askubuntu/ubuntuSSO/launchpad.

"Is it just me" ? :)

Comment: It's not just you, and this question has been asked before [here].

Comment: @guiverc you forgot to include the link to the question you mentioned! Also, if the question has been asked before, this one should be closed as a duplicate. ;)

Comment: Ive searched for similar question, only found 1 duplicate years ago, was an lp issue and was supposed to be fixed, and moreover, the error message was NOT the same; i so guess it is not the same issue?
Still, do you suggest me to open a bug on lp and link to this question?

Comment: OpenID errors are specific to the login mechanisms used in StackExchange.  This said, they've been trying to get rid of OpenID for eons.  This is something that StackExchange has to look into.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the email that you logged in to launchpad with and click recover account you will get the recovery email to reset your password and then you in.